# Row-wise updates in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

Say I have this dataframe:

```
>>> polars.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],list('abc'))
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 7   │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ 8   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 9   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Note that below I'm specifically asking about the case where columns are "unimporant" - i.e. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't necessarily depend on columns being named `a`, `b` and `c` or that there is a certain number of columns.

I can use the following to update a certain column at a certain row:

```
>>> polars.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],list('abc')).with_row_count().with_columns(a=polars.when(polars.col('row_nr') == 1).then(42).otherwise(polars.col('a'))).drop('row_nr')
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 7   │
│ 42  ┆ 5   ┆ 8   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 9   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

but that's a bit hard if I don't know that I should be updating `a`.

How can I do the following:

1. Replace the whole row - e.g. I want to replace the 2nd row with `43,42,41`:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 7   │
│ 43  ┆ 42  ┆ 41  │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 9   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

2. Replace any column in a certain row by condition - e.g. I want to negate any values `> 4` in 2nd row:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 7   │
│ 2   ┆ -5  ┆ -8  │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 9   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 4):

`pl.all` can be used as shorthand for every column (thus every element) in a `when` expresion. `cumcount` can replicate a row index lazily without any `with_row_count` column. Putting it all together, for part 2:

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.when((pl.all().cumcount() == 1) & (pl.all() > 4))
    .then(-pl.all())
    .otherwise(pl.all())
    .keep_name()
)
```

I'm not sure of a better way on part 1 outside of making the `df` temporarily one column, do a similar approach to above, then unnest it:

```py
df.select(x=pl.concat_list(pl.all())).select(
    x=pl.when(pl.col("x").cumcount() == 1)
    .then([43, 42, 41])
    .otherwise(pl.col("x"))
    .arr.to_struct(fields=df.columns)
).unnest("x")
```

Comment: you should do `cumcount` on `pl.first()` instead of `all` since the row count for each column is the same so no need to have it calculate it n times. Probably would never notice the performance hit in real life but if you've got enough columns it might add up to real amounts of time.

Comment: You could remove `.keep_name()` if you use `pl.all() * -1`. You could reposition the `.concat_list` and do it inside a single `.select` e.g. `pl.when(pl.first().cumcount() == 1).then([43, 42, 41]).otherwise(pl.concat_list(pl.all()))`

Comment: Is `keep_name` more expensive than a multiply by -1? Weird now that renames the column (to `literal`?) but unary minus doesn't. And thanks for that tip, @DeanMacGregor!

Answer (score 2):

Just use a generator/list comprehension.

```
df.select(
    (pl.when(pl.first().cumcount()==1)
        .then(pl.lit(x))
        .otherwise(pl.col(df.columns[i])))
        .alias(df.columns[i]) for i, x in enumerate([43,42,41])
)
```

The problem with this approach is that it relies on `df.columns` so you can't put this at the end of a chain. However, you can get around that if you put that in a function and monkey patch it into the DataFrame namespace. Just change all the references to `df` to self like this:

```
def replace_row(self, row_index, new_values):
    return self.select(
    (pl.when(pl.first().cumcount()==row_index)
        .then(pl.lit(x))
        .otherwise(pl.col(self.columns[i])))
        .alias(self.columns[i]) for i, x in enumerate(new_values)
)
pl.DataFrame.replace_row=replace_row
del replace_row
```

Now you can chain like this:

```
df.with_columns(d=pl.Series([2,8,1])).replace_row(0, [1,2,3,4])

shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ 8   ┆ 8   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 9   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

You can also register your own namespaces as [shown here](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.api.register_dataframe_namespace.html) but then the syntax for the method would be

```
df.mynamespace.replace_row()
```

and I prefer to just have it at the df level. If you were going to make a lot of these helper functions it'd probably make sense to put them all in their own namespace.